# C - Merge Two Linked Lists

Tags: c, linked-list

### Question

I'm trying to merge two linked lists. They each have headers which contain a beginning and ending node. This is the function. It returns a header with the new merged linked list; it takes as parameters two linked lists that will be merged.

I can't find what I am doing wrong. When return the merged header and use a function to print linked lists from its header it prints in loop two nodes forever. All the functions used in the code are working well; already tested in the rest of the software.

### Merge Function

```
header * merge_lists (header * h1, header * h2) {
  header * h3 = init_header();
  node * curr1 = h1->first;
  node * curr2 = h2->first;
  node * result;

  while (1) {
    if (curr1 == NULL && curr2 == NULL) break;
    if (curr1 == NULL){
      result = curr2;
      curr2 = curr2->next;
    }
    else if (curr2 == NULL){
      result = curr1;
      curr1 = curr1->next;
    }
    else if (curr1->name[0] > curr2->name[0]){
      result = curr1;
      curr1 = curr1->next;
    }
    else if (curr1->name[0] <= curr2->name[0]) {
      result = curr2;
      curr2 = curr2->next;
    }
    insert_beginning(h3, result);
  }
  return h3;
}
```

### Print Function

```
void print_list (header * head) {
  node * current = head->first;
  while (current != NULL){
    printf("%s %d\n", current->name, current->age);
    current = current->next;
  }
}
```

### Insert at Beginning Function

```
void insert_beginning (header * head, node * new_node) {
  if (head->quantity == 0){
    head->first = new_node;
    head->last = new_node;
    head->quantity++;
    return;
  }

  new_node->next = head->first;
  head->first = new_node;
  new_node->next->prev = new_node;
  head->quantity++;
}
```

### Node Struct

```
typedef struct node_struct {
  char name[30];
  int age;
  struct node_struct * prev;
  struct node_struct * next;
} node;
```

Comment: Of what type is `curr->name` ? And `if (curr1 == NULL && curr2 == NULL) break` would break if either is `NULL`, so you could end up leaving some data on the table.

Comment: name is array of char @c650 , I think that if both are null is because reached the end of both linked lists, so no data would be left on the table, right?

Comment: case of `curr1` is NULL and `curr2` isn't NULL : `if (curr1 == NULL && curr2 == NULL) break;` ==> `if (curr2 == NULL || curr1->name[0] > curr2->name[0]){` : `curr1(NULL)->name[0]` Oops!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY exactly. Thanks for typing faster than me!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY did some edits, now it should work right? ps.: still looping forever

Comment: @Vitor By changing your code, we have a moving target, which makes your post unclear of what you are asking.  Suggest reverting back to the original code.

Comment: @chux I tested before editing, it was a side bug, didn't move the target of the question since the same error still happening and just fixed the side bug so no one more would think it is the cause and loose their time  with it

Comment: _still looping forever_ : Perhaps, I think that there is a problem with the creation of the link.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY there is not, trust me, the insert_beginning which inserts node at the beginning is correct and tested in many ways. If you want I can post it here too

Comment: 1) `if (head->quantity == 0){
    head->first = new_node;` : `new_node->next` souble be `NULL` 2) `head->first = new_node;
  new_node->next = head->first;` : Make a circular reference. (Different from what Print function is expected)

Comment: @VitorCosta You need to post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). *"side bugs"*, and *"copied wrong in post"*, and missing pieces of code just waste everyone's time.

Answer (score 1):

Your insert code appears to have at least one bug:

```
void insert_beginning (header * head, node * new_node) {
  if (head->quantity == 0){
    head->first = new_node;
    head->last = new_node;
    head->quantity++;
    return;
  }

  // NOTE/BUG: this links new_node to itself
#if 0
  head->first = new_node;
  new_node->next = head->first;
  // NOTE/FIX: this is the correct way
#else
  new_node->next = head->first;
  head->first = new_node;
#endif

  // NOTE/BUG?: what about end of list?
#if 0
  new_node->next->prev = new_node;
#else
  if (new_node->next != NULL)
    new_node->next->prev = new_node;
#endif

  head->quantity++;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> The first bug I just copied wrong in post, I am sorry.

Okay, fair enough.

> But the second one: there is no way `new_node->next` will be `NULL` at this point since it will always be inserted at beginning and will always already have another node next.

That's indirectly part of the problem, I think.

I've gotten your code to work and produced a test program. I had to create some of the missing functions and structs.

I coded up a different merge function: `merge_lists2`. One of the big differences is that it doesn't just do (e.g.) `curr1 = curr1->next` but calls a new function that shifts off the first element [if needed] that removes all old `next/prev` links.

This is done in a new function `list_shift`. In particular, see the `NOTE/BUG` comment in that function.

Anyway, here's the updated and working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node_struct {
    char name[30];
    int age;
    struct node_struct *prev;
    struct node_struct *next;
} node;

typedef struct header_struct {
    node *first;
    node *last;
    int quantity;
} header;

void
print_list(header * head, const char *sym)
{
    node *current = head->first;

    printf("%s [fwd]:\n", sym);

    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("  %s %d\n", current->name, current->age);
        current = current->next;
    }
}

void
print_rlist(header * head, const char *sym)
{
    node *current = head->last;

    printf("%s [rev]:\n", sym);

    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("  %s %d\n", current->name, current->age);
        current = current->prev;
    }
}

void
insert_beginning(header * head, node * new_node)
{

#if 1
    new_node->prev = NULL;
#endif

    if (head->quantity == 0) {
        head->first = new_node;
        head->last = new_node;
        head->quantity++;
        return;
    }

    // NOTE/BUG: this links new_node to itself
#if 0
    head->first = new_node;
    new_node->next = head->first;
    // NOTE/FIX: this is the correct way
#else
    new_node->next = head->first;
    head->first = new_node;
#endif

    // NOTE/BUG?: what about end of list?
#if 0
    new_node->next->prev = new_node;
#else
    if (new_node->next != NULL)
        new_node->next->prev = new_node;
#endif

    head->quantity++;
}

void
insert_string(header * h, const char *str)
{
    node *ptr = calloc(1, sizeof(*ptr));

    strcpy(ptr->name, str);

    insert_beginning(h, ptr);
}

header *
init_header(void)
{
    header *h = calloc(1, sizeof(*h));

    return h;
}

header *
merge_lists1(header * h1, header * h2)
{
    header *h3 = init_header();
    node *curr1 = h1->first;
    node *curr2 = h2->first;
    node *result;

    while (1) {
        if (curr1 == NULL && curr2 == NULL)
            break;
        if (curr1 == NULL) {
            result = curr2;
            curr2 = curr2->next;
        }
        else if (curr2 == NULL) {
            result = curr1;
            curr1 = curr1->next;
        }
        else if (curr1->name[0] > curr2->name[0]) {
            result = curr1;
            curr1 = curr1->next;
        }
        else if (curr1->name[0] <= curr2->name[0]) {
            result = curr2;
            curr2 = curr2->next;
        }
        insert_beginning(h3, result);
    }
    return h3;
}

node *
list_shift(header * h, node * cur)
{

    do {
        // bug out if we do _not_ yet need to dequeue an element from this list
        if (cur != NULL)
            break;

        // bug out if we're at the end of the list
        cur = h->first;
        if (cur == NULL)
            break;

        // fix the head chain pointer
        h->first = cur->next;

        // fix the tail chain pointer
        if (cur == h->last)
            h->last = NULL;

        cur->prev = NULL;

        // NOTE/BUG: the smoking gun -- adding this fixed things
        cur->next = NULL;
    } while (0);

    return cur;
}

header *
merge_lists2(header * h1, header * h2)
{
    header *h3 = init_header();
    node *curr1 = NULL;
    node *curr2 = NULL;
    node *result;

    while (1) {
        curr1 = list_shift(h1, curr1);
        curr2 = list_shift(h2, curr2);

        if ((curr1 == NULL) && (curr2 == NULL))
            break;

        if (curr1 == NULL) {
            result = curr2;
            curr2 = NULL;
        }
        else if (curr2 == NULL) {
            result = curr1;
            curr1 = NULL;
        }
        else if (curr1->name[0] > curr2->name[0]) {
            result = curr1;
            curr1 = NULL;
        }
        else {
            result = curr2;
            curr2 = NULL;
        }

        insert_beginning(h3, result);
    }

    return h3;
}

// main -- main program
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *cp;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (; argc > 0; --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        switch (cp[1]) {
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    header *h1 = init_header();

    insert_string(h1, "jkl");
    insert_string(h1, "def");
    print_list(h1, "h1");
    print_rlist(h1, "h1");

#if 1
    header *h2 = init_header();

    insert_string(h2, "ttt");
    insert_string(h2, "ghi");
    insert_string(h2, "abc");
    print_list(h2, "h2");
    print_rlist(h2, "h2");
#endif

#if 0
    header *h3 = merge_lists1(h1, h2);

    print_list(h3, "h3");
    print_rlist(h3, "h3");
#endif

#if 1
    header *h3 = merge_lists2(h1, h2);

    print_list(h3, "h3");
    print_rlist(h3, "h3");
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

*Side note:* You're only comparing the first character of the strings, so you may want to use `strcmp`

Comment: The first bug I just copied wrong in post, I am sorry. But the second one: there is no way new_node->next will be NULL at this point since it will always be inserted at beginning and will always already have another node next.